# How to find all sub-directories named include in cmake

Tags: cmake

How do I find all directories named include in cmake? For instance, if the directory structure is like that:

```
root
include/
a/
  include/
b/
  c/
     d/
        include/
```

I'd like to assign to a variable all found paths:

```
root/include
root/a/include
root/b/c/d/include
```

I tried to use GLOBE_RECURSE, but with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure that a solution exists in CMake.  I did come up with a solution on Linux that uses execute_process and find.  Similar solutions can be made for other OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE include_dirs LIST_DIRECTORIES true
    RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "include")
```

This works since CMake 3.3, as option *LIST_DIRECTORIES* appears only in this version. (By default, for *GLOB_RECURSE* mode option *LIST_DIRECTORIES* is false).

Comment: Not only the "include" paths were assigned to "include_dirs", but also their parent folders: root/, a/, b/, b/c, b/c/d. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Hm, actually I have checked that with files, not with dirs. I will test dirs tomorrow.